# Adding a fas class to existing star-rating class for Storefront theme - to change hollow stars to filled stars for product rating

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, storefront

I'm using the Storefront theme for Woocomerce/Wordpress. Having the issue where product ratings are showing hollow stars rather than filled stars. I found that the solution is appending the "fas" Font Awesome class to the existing star-rating class.

[Before adding fas class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEYWz.png)

[After adding fas class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RZlI.png)

I'm trying to add the fas class using the Snippet plugin.

What I have so far:

```
<?php
add_action( 'star', function () { ?>
  <script>
    function addNewClass() {
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("star-rating");
      for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].className += " fas";
      }
   }
  </script>
<?php } );
```

Not really working. Any guidance?

Comment: the website is https://www.malaysiatoys.com

Comment: so you added a new Javascript function named `addNewClass()` but I don't see you call it anywhere. Are we missing that part of the code? Just to try something add the following: `addNewClass();` right before `</script>`

Comment: still doesn't work. any other ideas? Sorry am a total noob here